# Callable spritesheet class for any spritesheet

Tags: python, class, pygame, draw, sprite-sheet

I was wondering how you would code a class in python, which when called would cycle through any sprite sheet. For example, if Spritesheet(spritesheet, x, y) was called, the sprite sheet given would be cycled through and would appear at the given co-ordinates?

Comment: use instance variable to keep current sprite and chage this variable in every execution. And when you go to last sprite then you set first sprite. Eventually probably there is `itertools.cycle()`

Comment: problem is only cycling. Displaying is not so important.

Comment: do you mean you what to run the same class with different `spritesheet` ? But every `spritesheet` may have different number of elements. OR maybe for every `spritesheet` you need separated cycle ? Then `spritesheet` should be instance of class which can cycle

Answer (score 0):

Important is only cycling to get next image. Displaying is not important when you know how to get next image.

---

It is not problem for single `spritesheet`. You keep data and current index in the class and use method which get element from current index, increase it and if it bigger then length of data then it set current = 0

```
class Cycler():

    def __init__(self, spritesheet):
        self.spritesheet = spritesheet
        self.lenght = len(self.spritesheet)
        self.current = 0
        
    def next(self):
        value = self.spritesheet[self.current]
        
        self.current += 1
        if self.current == self.length:
            self.current = 0

        # OR
        #self.current = (self.current + 1) % self.length
      
        return value

spritesheet = ["A", "B", "C"]
cycler = Cycler(spritesheet)

for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        print(x, y, cycler.next())
```

Result:

```
0 0 A
0 1 B
0 2 C
0 3 A
0 4 B
1 0 C
1 1 A
1 2 B
1 3 C
1 4 A
2 0 B
2 1 C
2 2 A
2 3 B
2 4 C
3 0 A
3 1 B
3 2 C
3 3 A
3 4 B
4 0 C
4 1 A
4 2 B
4 3 C
4 4 A
```

---

The same you can do with `itertools.cycle`

```
import itertools

spritesheet = ["A", "B", "C"]
cycler = itertools.cycle(spritesheet)        
            
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        print(x, y, next(cycler))
```

---

If you need more spritesheets then you can create more cyclers

```
import itertools

spritesheet1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
cycler1 = itertools.cycle(spritesheet1)

spritesheet2 = ["X", "Y", "Z"]
cycler2 = itertools.cycle(spritesheet2)        
            
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        if x % 2:
            print(x, y, next(cycler2))
        else:
            print(x, y, next(cycler1))
```

Result:

```
0 0 A
0 1 B
0 2 C
0 3 A
0 4 B
1 0 X
1 1 Y
1 2 Z
1 3 X
1 4 Y
2 0 C
2 1 A
2 2 B
2 3 C
2 4 A
3 0 Z
3 1 X
3 2 Y
3 3 Z
3 4 X
4 0 B
4 1 C
4 2 A
4 3 B
4 4 C
```